# Angular 2 persistent data storage on refresh or rerouting to external urls and back

Tags: angular

I am storing data in two services but I have to redirect my user to facebook for authentication and paypal to make a payment and both times that clears out all the data stored in my services. I have placed some data in localstorage but it only stores strings afaik. How do I persistently store objects? or is that not possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

Answer (score 0):

Store objects in local storage as strings,

Use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to convert your object to string and [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to parse it back into your object representation.

Answer (score 0):

You can stringify objects like that:

```
localStorage.setItem(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Then to retrieve the object:

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('obj'));
```

Also there is a service for angular called [localForage](https://github.com/ocombe/angular-localForage).

Comment: The service is for angular 1, sorry.

Comment: I meant I'll give storing stringified objects a try :P What is the max capacity you can use in localstorage and how do you check which devices or browsers dont allow using localstorage?

Comment: you can use this to check whether local storage exists or not 


if(typeof Storage !== "undefined")
  // local strage supported
else
  // No web storage

Comment: Capacity varies a lot across browsers so see this table http://dev-test.nemikor.com/web-storage/support-test/

Comment: You may use localForage (this time it's not an angular service) https://github.com/localForage/localForage which is more crossbrowser.